# Find $f(n)$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{1.23}\sim f(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, power-series, generating-functions

Find $f(n)$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{1.23}\sim f(n)$.

I tried to use generating functions. To proceed I need to calculate $\sum_{n\geq0} n^{1.23}x^{n}$ (or something asymptotically similar, because I don't need the exact solution). I know how to do $\sum_{n\geq0} nx^{n}$ or $\sum_{n\geq0} n^{2}x^{n}$, but not anything in between. So after all I guess this method won't work here.

I would appreciate any tips!

Comment: A sum can be approximated by an integral...

Comment: No further help needed, thank you.